# Change format of AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX response like this

```
"12-02-2017,12-02-2017,11-02-2017,10-02-2017"
```

and i want convert this response into

```
   var sortDates =["12-02-2017","18-02-2017","11-02-2017","10-02-2017"];
```

Any questions, please comment.

Comment: [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: can you help me sort list of dates and implode array Array ( [0] => 10-02-2017 [1] => 11-02-2017 [2] => 12-02-2017 [3] => 04-02-2017 ) array is like this using php??

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**:

```js
var resp = "12-02-2017,12-02-2017,11-02-2017,10-02-2017";
resp = resp.split(',');
console.log(resp);
```

Comment: can you help me sort list of dates and implode array Array
(
    [0] => 10-02-2017
    [1] => 11-02-2017
    [2] => 12-02-2017
    [3] => 04-02-2017
)
array is like this using php??

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisZulifqar, how do you want to be sorted? Ascending or descending?

Comment: Ascending ORDER

Comment: Assuming you have the array in a variable called `$dates` you can do the next thing: `usort($dates, "compare");

function compare($a, $b){ 
    return strcmp($a, $b); 
}`. To order them descending just switch the order of `$a` and `$b` in the `strcmp()` function.

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisZulifqar, then you can just `implode` the array by `,` let's say like `$dates = implode(',', $dates);`